# Как добавить несколько ImageView в onBindViewHolder в Android?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Всем привет.
Тяжело даётся изучение разработки под Андроид и Java после Unity и C#, поэтому возникает полно разных вопросов.

У меня создан RecyclerView и Adapter, куда я добавляю данные из MainActivity.java:

```
data = new ArrayList<>();
data.add(new ProjectItem("Name", "04 May","@tester",
                         R.drawable.ava, R.drawable.logo_black,
                         new int[]{R.drawable.logo_white, R.drawable.logo_blue}));
projectAdapter = new ProjectAdapter(this, data);
projectRecyclerView.setAdapter(projectAdapter);
projectRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Всё работает корректно, но в последнем параметре мне нужно передать массив из картинок (`new int[]{R.drawable.logo_white, R.drawable.logo_blue}`) и затем добавить его к каждому холдеру и в instrumentsLayout в Adapter.java:

```
public class ProjectsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView title, date, username;
    ImageView avatar, instrument;
    LinearLayout instrumentsLayout;

    public ProjectsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.projectTitle);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.projectDate);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        avatar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        instrument = itemView.findViewById(R.id.instrument);

        instrumentsLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.projectInstruments);
    }
}
```

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProjectsViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.title.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.date.setText(data.get(position).getDate());
    holder.username.setText(data.get(position).getUsername());
    holder.avatar.setImageResource(data.get(position).getAvatar());
    holder.instrument.setImageResource(data.get(position).getInstrument());

    int[] projectInstrumentsList = data.get(position).getProjectInstrumentsList();

    for(int i = 0; i < projectInstrumentsList.length; i++)
    {
        if (projectInstrumentsList[i] == R.drawable.logo_white)
        {
            //Тут нужно добавлять View в Layout
        }
    }
}
```

У меня получается добавить например одну картинку:

```
holder.avatar.setImageResource(data.get(position).getAvatar());
```

В каждый холдер приходит int массив projectInstrumentsList, который я передаю из MainActivity. Не могу понять как перебирая массив добавить все картинки по ключу.

В гугле советуют такой подход:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(holder.instrumentsLayout.getContext());
holder.instrumentsLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Но здесь мне непонятно как получить картинки из holder.instrumentsLayout.getContext().

Подскажите, как наиболее безболезненно это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(holder.instrumentsLayout.getContext());
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
imageView.setImageResource(projectInstrumentsList[i]);

holder.instrumentsLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: Пытаюсь выполнить в цикле, добавляется только первая картинка из массива:

`for(int i = 0; i < projectInstrumentsList.length; i++)
{
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(holder.instrumentsLayout.getContext());
imageView.setImageResource(projectInstrumentsList[i]);
            holder.instrumentsLayout.addView(imageView);
}
`
Добавляю массив так:
`new int[]{R.drawable.drums_logo_black,R.drawable.guitar_logo_black,R.drawable.vocal_logo_black}`

Comment: Да все правильно. Странно что не добавляет остальные элементы. Включайте дебаггер, ставьте бряки и проверяйте код построчно.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо! Намудрил с выравниванием в Layout.